# Looping to update article codes on one server based on queries on another server

Tags: php, performance, sql, mysql

I've read somewhere on Stack Overflow that doing queries in a loop is very inefficient. It will hammer your SQL server and make your script very slow.

Sample code:

```
// Connect to SQL Server 1
$query = "SELECT * FROM
articles
";

$resource = mysql_query($query);
$articles = array();
while $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource) {
    $articles[] = $record;
}

// The part that bothers me:
// (Note: this is executed on a different sql server)
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    // Connect to SQL server 2
    $sQuery = "SELECT artcode FROM articles WHERE id='".$article['id']."'";
    $sResource = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($sResource) == 1) {
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sResource);
        // Connect to SQL Server 1 again ...
        // This will be executed on the first sql server again
        $uQuery = "UPDATE articles SET artcode='".$data['artcode']."' WHERE id='".$article['id']."' LIMIT 1";
        $uResource = mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

How would I go and make this code more efficient. (In best case scenario avoiding doing the query in a loop.)

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions

Comment: @Justinas I know :D It was just for the example.

Comment: You can do the update without select before. An update will not throw error if not found the record to be updated. You may can use IN eventually

Comment: Not sure about the current example code since you are selecting and updating the same table. If the operation is done on multiple table then using `update with join` would be the most efficient way.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty As i mentioned in the commenentary, the the second article table is on a different sql server

Comment: USe implode on that array and change the condition to `WHERE id IN "(".implode(',',$article['id']).")"` removing also the loop.Same for UPDATE

Comment: yes you can use the join update with a single query, not sure how you will access the different DB with the same connection but its possible in mysql when you are executing the query from an user who is having access to both DB.

Comment: is it in another different server or just another database ?

Comment: It is another server as well, not just another database

Comment: You seem to be implying that there are `mysql_connect()` calls as well. Could you include those calls in the code (anonymizing the connection parameters, of course)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem**: there is a query being performed inside a for-loop.

```
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    // Connect to SQL server 2
    $sQuery = "SELECT artcode FROM articles WHERE id='".$article['id']."'";
}
```

**The solution**: move the query outside of the for-loop

```
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    $articleIds[] = $article['id'];
}
$sQuery = "SELECT artcode FROM articles WHERE id IN '".implode(',',$articleIds)."'";
```

Then loop over the result of that query and peform the update query. Again, this update query be moved outside the loop. Check [this](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

**if you can access the second database from the same connection**

use this query

```
UPDATE articles a1 inner join YOURDB.articles a2 on a1.id=a2.id
set a2.artcode = a1.artcode
```

but if your database is in another server i'm afraid you can't make it in one query

Comment: Good suggestion indeed but The first database is a local one, and the second database is in a remote location. You cannot do joins to another server. That's what made this hard for me :)

Answer (score 0):

## Less is more

I guess there's more going on in your code, but from what I can see you wouldn't need the whole article records. So this is what I would do:

```
$set = mysql_query('SELECT id, artcode FROM articles',$db1);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($set)) {
  extract($row);
  mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET artcode = '$artcode' WHERE id = '$id'",$db2);
}
```

As you can see it's short and simple. Yes, this is all you need.

You could try to do multiple updates in one SQL command, but that technique seems a bit clumsy to me. You would only do that if this is way too slow. It will complicate your code no end, and that makes debugging a lot harder.

Do I need to repeat that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated? No, I don't think so.

Comment: this wont work for he selects the artcode from a different db-connection. And he performs an UPDATE query for each article. Could be 1000thnds of aricles

Comment: As far as I can see all articles are selected from the source database, which is the same as not doing any selecting at all. Please remove your '-1' if that was the reason for it. You're right, there could be very many articles. We simply don't know.